# protect SQL injection on django Rest API

Tags: django, sql-injection

For penetration testing purpose, I am tring sql-injection to my Django Rest API,And I can successfully take schema , table and rows information by **SQLmap**.
I was try several times,It was just simple API.

*I was create function based view, also a class base view,
I was try with cursor and also try ORM.raw query try with parameterize.*

but every time I can injected sql by **SQLMAP**.

I can't believe, how it happens, but I see result in my implementation. I am sure that I follow proper way.

Please suggest my , how can I protect all type of API, which url have params.

Comment: Without seeing your code that allows SQL injection it's not possible to answer your question. The standard Django mechanisms for accessing request data will usually protect you from such vulnerabilities, don't use raw SQL and use a form to clean incoming data